# Dynamics GP: Not able to figure out the tables for invoice reports

Tags: report, microsoft-dynamics, invoice, dynamics-gp

I am completely new to dynamics GP and know nothing about it.

I have a requirement to generate a report and i will explain the scenario below:

I have a Facility which has Storage Tanks which in turn has Compartments and for each compartment a customer has to pay some amount monthly or invoices are created for compartments. Now , i am totally confused which tables to look at in dynamics GP db and how to create a INVOICE report.

Comment: http://dyndeveloper.com/DynModule.aspx

Comment: hi devlin it helped to figure out the tables.thank you. are there any built in invoice reports on GP  ?